# Spring ViewResolver : xml conf ok, the SAME in java fail

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

Hello!

As said in the title I'm trying to export my view resolver config from the classic xml to java conf. (I don't think I'll enter in the reason of this choice..?)

My previous conf is :

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
...
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="ca.mat8j8.controller" />

<!-- freemarker config -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
</bean>

<!--
View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. If you need
different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the resource bundle resolver.
-->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
</bean>
```

This way, it work without problem.

Now I try to get rid of my xml conf like that:

web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

...

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!--Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext instead of default XmlWebApplicationContext.--> 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <!--Custom web configuration annotated class.  -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>ca.mat8j8.configuration.WebConfiguration</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I empty dispatcher-servlet.xml, and create WebConfiguration :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "ca.mat8j8.controller" })
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    final FreeMarkerViewResolver resolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    resolver.setCache(true);
    resolver.setPrefix("");
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
    factory.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/views/");
    final FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setConfiguration(factory.createConfiguration());
    return configurer;
}
}
```

On startup, I can see that it pass through my java webConf(breakpoints).
In my head, it should do the same thing, but when I try now to reach my "home" view (which worked with the xml conf), I've got this very interesting :

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'home' in servlet with name 'dispatcher'
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1211)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
.....
```

For info, I work with tomcat 8, java 8, and spring 4.1.5.

Thank you to have read so far, thanks in advance for your answers ;-)

Comment: Note that there is absolutely no relation between your declared `DispatcherServlet` and the `<context-param>` you've shown. The `DispatcherServlet` uses an `<init-param>` for its config location, not the `<context-param>`.

Comment: Hi Sotirios. Are you sure?

I've got the feeling that the context-param is relevant, because spring actually find my "dispatcher-servlet.xml" file when having my conf in there.

As you can see I use the "init-param" when trying to put the conf in the java file....
But... it don't work...

Comment: It finds `dispatcher-servlet.xml` because your `<servlet-name>` is `dispatcher` and by default it looks for `<servlet-name>-servlet.xml`, which resolves to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. The `<context-param>` is used by the `ContextLoaderListener`.

Comment: OK! Thank you very much for that! Even if it don't solve my problem, I'll go to bed smarter  tonight ;-)

Comment: Did you resolve this? Running into the same problem and looking for a quickfix